# Lens flare/beam explosion

Tags: animation, effects

I'm trying to create a lens flare light explosion in Blender. Something very similar to [this](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-1085657105-lens-flare-effects-on-black-background) but faster to suggest a build up to an explosive light moment.

I've followed two tutorials on Youtube to try and bend them to fit:

- [This one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fv_5UBzJvEs&t=34s) was a bit too nebula looking
- and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CE9j12yKsoQ&pp=ygUYbGlnaHQgYmVhbSBibGVuZGVyIGVldmVl) worked but didn't give that kinda punchy moment

I guess it could be something to do with the Glare node or maybe fog but I'm just unsure how to put it all together to achieve this effect.

Would anyone have any suggestions about how best to do this or any tutorials that you've come across that might suit? Thanks all

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Create a sphere with Emission, make it bigger and bigger, use some effects in the Compositor, like Blur, Glare and Sun Beams, in my opinion you can do most of the effect in the Compositor